# Is DP helpful only in recurisve problems?

Tags: recursion, dynamic-programming

is Dyanamic Programming helpful only in recursive problems , Can it be used in Some other use cases or problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DP is a very broad topic that can solve a wide variety of problems. Consider the factorials example:

```
static long fact(int n){
    if(n==0)return 1;
    if(fact[n]!=-1)return fact[n];
    return fact[n]=n*fact(n-1);

}
```

This is a recursive method, but it is also equivalently DP to do this:

```
long[] fact = new long[20];
fact[0] = 1;
for(int i = 1; i < 20;i++) fact[i] = i * fact[i-1];
```

It can be shown that every problem that can be solved with recursion can be solved iteratively. However, recursion is a powerful tool that can make code much easier to understand, write, be less unweildy, and overall more useful in certain scenarios. It is up to the programmer to determine which problems should be solved iteratively and which recursively, but DP can be used to solve many problems either way.